# Xcode 4 issue with AppDelegate.m adding view controller - xcode 4.2 storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, xcode-storyboard

I'm having a problem. I'm following this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_apns/)

The part I'm having is in my AppDelegate.m

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Register for alert notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.

    [_window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

My issue is that I'm using a storyboard as my main view. I have no xibs. The error I'm receiving is " Use of undeclared identifier `viewContoller`. I'm guessing it has something to do with storyboard. Can someone please let me know how to make it work with storyboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit these two lines:

```
[_window addSubview:viewController.view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the storyboard whichever view controller you mark as the "Initial View Controller" will be the rootViewController of the window.

If you are using a storyboard (and/or ARC), you may want to look for a tutorial that uses those features.